# Shortcut keys not working on Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

yesterday I installed Windows 7 Ultimate x64. The problem is that I have some programs on the quicklaunch and I want some of them to be opened by hitting a shorcut key.

Well, the procedure to set it is very straightforward. Right click on the program shorcut, focus on Shorcut key field and press your desire shortcut. Apply/Ok. Done.

Well, it's not working. I've tried several keys combination, I've tred moving the shortcut to the desktop, my user folder, C:\ root, wherever. It simply doesn't want t work... While on XP this worked me just fine.

I've searched on google and I've found some people having the same problem, but I didn't found any solution to it.

Any idea?

If not, could you recommend a very lightweight macros program to set hotkeys to open apps and those sort of things?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried Ctrl+Alt, Ctrl+Shift, Ctrl+Alt+Shift, F1-F12...
I forgot to say that the hotkeys HAS to be Ctrl+Alt+A/B/C/D or Ctrl+Alt+1/2/3/4 or Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2/F3/F4 becaue I have an IR remote controller which has 4 buttons that sends those keystrokes to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the keys working, any time after installing Windows 7? Check [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/d569b5c4-e22d-479a-b962-5dddc688932c) forum and [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/b5404e17-144a-4628-83d6-d3de11b72562) forum. They mention corrupt user profile can also be a reason for this and some restriction for special keys also.

Make sure the actual shortcut is available in Desktop or startmenu hierarchy as this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/134552) says.

As far as a mapper, you could try [Hoekey](http://www.brothersoft.com/hoekey-download-68503.html) or [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/)

Comment: I pinned the shortcut to the start menu and it seems to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by:

1. Deleting the non-functioning shortcut.
2. Selecting "Send to..." on the target document and choosing **Desktop.**
3. Opened properties on the newly created shortcut and setting the keyboard shortcut.

The first shortcut I created which didn't work was created in the same folder as the target and then moved the shortcut to the desktop. Why that didn't work eludes me but the 3 steps outlined above fixed the issue in my case.